# Python multiprocessing's Process vs. Pool for CPU/Memory optimization

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am doing concurrent programming, and I noticed the following:

Version 1 multiprocessing.Process():

```
# huge_df is a giant pandas.DataFrame(), i.e. 1 billion rows, 50 cols
mgr_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
jobs = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(huge_df, mgr_dict, i) for in in xrange(2000) ]
for j in jobs:
    j.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
# blows out all my cores, grinds server to a halt
```

Version 2 multiprocessing.Pool():

```
# huge_df is a giant pandas.DataFrame(), i.e. 1 billion rows, 50 cols
mgr_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
args_iterable = [ (huge_df, mgr_dict, i) for i in xrange(2000) ]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(worker, args_iterable)  # worker in this example deconstructs tuple into separate vars
pool.close()
pool.join()
# takes a very long time to begin using fully allotted CPU resources
```

Hence, I am wondering:

1. Does multiprocess.Process share the same 'huge_df' for example, while multiprocess.Pool pickles it for each process? I.e. is multiprocess.Pool slower because it is I/O bound while this huge_df is copied to every process? I noticed that each thread ends up requiring an approximately equivalent amount of memory. (Or, does multiprocess.Process actually lock shared data, so only one thread can used it, even read-only, at a time?)
2. If my presumption in 1 is correct, is there either:

   - An idiom for limiting the number of multiprocessing.Process()s that run at once?
   - A way to share the huge_df between multiple multiprocessing.Pool() processes (that is also OOP compliant, i.e. not a global var)?

Comment: Why are you making `args_iterable` into a list instead of just using a generator expression? If you fix that, does the problem change?

Comment: Also, how many cores do you have? And do you have hyperthreading (or whatever AMD's equivalent is called)? It's possible that you've got, say, 4 HT cores, therefore 8 "logical cores", and `Pool` is defaulting to only 4 processes at a time, and your code happens to be almost perfectly hyperthreadable so you're only seeing 50% usage.

Comment: Anyway, I think the question's assumptions are probably wrong, but the answer to part 2b is to pass the dict to each process in the pool, instead of each task, by using the `initializer`/`initargs` arguments.